# Chrome rendering MathJax equations with a trailing vertical line

Tags: google-chrome, pandoc, mathjax, jupyter

I am working through Andrew Ng's machine learning course on Coursera using the Octave kernel for Jupyter and of course MathJax provides the equation rendering. This thin bar appears on the right side of every equation, and only in Chrome. Any thoughts on where in the stack things might be going wrong?

[image: Screenshot of vertical line in Jupyter equations]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is a known issue caused by Chrome changing its rounding behavior. It will be fixed in the next release. See https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1300

Comment: FYI the fix was released as part of MathJax v2.6.0 at the end of December 2015.

Comment: I had this same issue because I was using the 2.4 CDN URL. This URL gives you the latest version: https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML

Comment: @minrk lists the solution to this related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35171714/ipython-jupyter-notebook-producing-ghost-line-in-all-equations

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 11):

A quick and dirty method is right click one of them and select another renderer in `Math Setting -> Math Renderer`

Another method is create a bookmark of this link: `javascript:$('.math>span').css("border-left-color","transparent")` and click it in pages that use mathjax.

Comment: great, thank you. I am using jupyter via sagemath and this trailing bar was very annoying. now I just add a cell containing %%javascript and your js line and all is nice!

Answer (score 4):

If your MathJax is not the latest version, you can add this to the css style:

```
.MathJax nobr>span.math>span{border-left-width:0 !important};
```

then this problem can be solved.