# IPython (Jupyter) notebook producing ghost line in all equations

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, mathjax

I installed IPython / Jupyter using pip on a new machine (Macbook Air with El Capitan). In a fairly simple notebook of mine (created with the same version of the whole stack) all equations, inline or not, suddenly have a vertical line on the right hand side; same height as the embedded image.

This is the case even for a single inline symbol such as `$x$`. I have no complicated macros or any weird LaTeX hacking going on.

Does anybody know this?

Here's a picture.

[image]

Comment: I've been experiencing the same issue and was just about to post the same question. If you don't mind slightly less pretty mathematics output, you can right-click any of the equations and then select Math Settings > Math Renderer > Fast HTML. In general it looks fine but becomes clunky with matrix expressions and some inline expressions with \displaystyle set, for example. I'll be following this thread in the hopes of a better solution though!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This is a change in Chrome, affecting MathJax 2.5, which ships with Jupyter Notebook 4.1. Notebook 4.2 will bundle MathJax 2.6, which will fix this problem. In the meantime, you can tell the notebook to use latest MathJax from the CDN, by adding to `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`:

```
c.NotebookApp.mathjax_url = "https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js"
```

Other browsers do not appear to be affected.

Comment: ...And if such a file does not exist, first run `jupyter notebook --generate-config` . (See http://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html )

Comment: Just had the same problem with Safari. It is solved by the very same procedure. Thanks

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.