# Ipython Notebook - Latex inside markdown table

Tags: latex, markdown, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to create a markdown table with inline latex inside (like `$$ 1+2 = 3 $$`).
Here is my example code so far:

```
| A | B | C | $$(A \implies B)$$ | $$\vee$$ |  $$(B \implies \neg A)$$
| :- | :- | :- | :- | :- | :-
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6
```

But the outcome is rather strange:

[image]

Any ideas how to prevent this line breaking?

Comment: Oh and I also tried using single $ signs, like `$(A \implies B)$` - same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay my fault, haven't looked into enough details on this .. found the answer myself with some further research.

I noticed the `|` at the end of every equation and looked into this and found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35245068/5307891):

> This is a change in Chrome, affecting MathJax 2.5, which ships with Jupyter Notebook 4.1. Notebook 4.2 will bundle MathJax 2.6, which will fix this problem. In the meantime, you can tell the notebook to use latest MathJax from the CDN, by adding to `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`:
>
> ```
> c.NotebookApp.mathjax_url = "https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js"
> ```

An alternative workaround would be, to set the markdown cell math renderer to "Fast HTML", as mentioned by Richard Ambler in the comments to the same question linked above.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.