# How to git rid of extra "|" from latex in python Jupyter notebook markdown

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, mathjax

Does anyone have this issue ? I'm using latex in markdown by  either "$" or "$$" in jupyter notebook.

For example, here's what show if I do  `$\mu$`   or `$$\mu$$` in the markdown in notebook.

[image]

There is an extra "|" at the end everytime I use this.

Any idea ?

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35171714/ipython-jupyter-notebook-producing-ghost-line-in-all-equations) solve the problem?

Comment: yes thank you so much !!