# Mathjax equation got sign `|` on every formula

Tags: google-chrome, ckeditor, mathjax

I have this mathjax in TeX

```
x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}
```

Current output:

[image]

How to remove the vertical line `|` in this formula? I used Mathjax in CKEditor

Another image for your information:

[image]

Comment: I can not reproduce this error. The formula is ok, the additional bar could be from script implementation. You should provide more information about your script installation code. Did you check different browsers?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/34277967/1339651.

Comment: In mozilla its ok..only goggle chrome.

Answer (score 2):

According to other SO posts linked to this one, this is Chrome issue and it has been worked around in latest MathJax version 2.6.

To work around this problem in CKEditor you need to request the latest MathJax library version (or at least 2.6 which happens to be the latest at the time of writing). You can do this by setting below code directly in your HTML page:

```
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
        extraPlugins: 'mathjax',
        mathJaxLib: 'http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/2.6-latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML'
    } );
```

You can also put `mathJaxLib` into `config.js` file, like this:

```
config.mathJaxLib = 'http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/2.6-latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML';
```

Please don't forget to request same script on target page where math formulas will be displayed. For more details, please see: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_mathjax

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.