# Subscript and superscript in python pandas column names

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

Is it possible to format a column name in Pandas to have subscripts superscripts? I tried using dollars as $x_a^2$:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(list([1,2,3]),columns=['$x_a^2$'])
```

but in jupyter notebook I get a strange | character in the end
[image]

Comment: Which OS and browser are you using? Works for me with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Chrome.

Comment: Linux mint 18.1, chrome

Comment: This is a JavaScript bug in chrome I believe. I fixed it by overwriting a global CSS property. But I'm using new version of jupyter and don't see the problem anymore. What you're seeing is a right side border. https://github.com/benweet/stackedit/issues/916

Comment: Ok, I guess i will learn living with it..

Comment: @aless80 also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/34277967/2336654

Comment: @piRSquared it sounds good. if you post a quick answer I will accept it